# RShiny: Pop Up Box after Long Computation

Tags: r, shiny, popup, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a Pop Up box that say's "Hey the computation is done" after a computational process that takes about 10 minutes (optimization of a function). Code Snippet:

```
observeEvent(input$submit, {
out <- reactive(optim(params, lower = lowerBounds, upper = upperBounds, function(x) (theFunction(x) - 800.000)^2))

    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Somewhat important message",
      "This is a somewhat important message.",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      footer = NULL
    ))}
```

I thought that the code would pretty much pause until the optimization function was completed, but as soon as I hit "Submit" the optimization starts and the pop up box is shown. How would I go about having the pop up box show *after* the optimization function is completed?

Comment: Could you add a fully runnable app snippet with `ui` and `server`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to fix this is to separate the long-running calculation into it's own reactive expression, and then use `req()` to now show the modal before the computation is finished.

Under is an example which I think achieves what you want. In the example I use:

- `bindEvent()` to make sure that my long-running function `foo()` is not run before the button is clicked. I save the result to `out`.
- `req(out())` to make sure that `renderText()` is not run before the computation of `foo()` is finished. Since the modal is produced inside `renderText()` it doesn't pop up before `foo()` is finished.

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr) # only needed for the pipes

foo <- function() {

    Sys.sleep(2)

    "done!"

}

ui <- fluidPage(

    actionButton("submit", label = "Submit"),
    textOutput("res")

)

server <- function(input, output) {


    out <- reactive({
        foo()
    }) %>%
        bindEvent(input$submit)

    output$res <- renderText({

        req(out())

        showModal(
            modalDialog(
                title = "Somewhat important message",
                "This is a somewhat important message.",
                easyClose = TRUE,
                footer = NULL
            )
        )

        out()
        
    })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```